# insert a column in database using ORE

Tags: r

```
table in database: student

df - stud

name    exp     salary      edu
joy     4       35000
ram     5       45000
steve   2       23000
john    8       100000

a new data frame - edu

edu
masters
masters 
bachelors
PHD
```

I need to add the new data frame into the oracle database using Oracle R Enterprise - ORE.

issue that I face here is the rows shuffle when i join to dataframes.

I can write a code like this but the rows shuffle.

```
df <- data.frame(stud, edu)
ore.exec("INSERT INTO student(name, exp, salary, edu))
```